# Why copyBuffer implements while loop

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how `copyBuffer` works under the hood, but what is not clear to me is the use of while loop

```
for {
        nr, er := src.Read(buf)
        //...
}
```

Full code below:

```
// copyBuffer is the actual implementation of Copy and CopyBuffer.
// if buf is nil, one is allocated.
func copyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error) {
    // If the reader has a WriteTo method, use it to do the copy.
    // Avoids an allocation and a copy.
    if wt, ok := src.(WriterTo); ok {
        return wt.WriteTo(dst)
    }
    // Similarly, if the writer has a ReadFrom method, use it to do the copy.
    if rt, ok := dst.(ReaderFrom); ok {
        return rt.ReadFrom(src)
    }
    size := 32 * 1024
    if l, ok := src.(*LimitedReader); ok && int64(size) > l.N {
        if l.N < 1 {
            size = 1
        } else {
            size = int(l.N)
        }
    }
    if buf == nil {
        buf = make([]byte, size)
    }
    for {
        nr, er := src.Read(buf)
        if nr > 0 {
            nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])
            if nw > 0 {
                written += int64(nw)
            }
            if ew != nil {
                err = ew
                break
            }
            if nr != nw {
                err = ErrShortWrite
                break
            }
        }
        if er != nil {
            if er != EOF {
                err = er
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return written, err
}
```

It writes to `nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])` when `nr` is the number of bytes read, so why is the `while loop` necessary?

Comment: to put it in very simple words, this loop has more than one exit condition, thus the infinite `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that `src` does not implement `WriterTo` and `dst` does not implement `ReaderFrom`, since otherwise we would not get down to the `for` loop at all.

Let's further assume, for simplicity, that `src` does not implement `LimitedReader`, so that `size` is `32 * 1024`: 32 kBytes.  (There is no real loss of generality here as `LimitedReader` just allows the source to pick an even smaller number, at least in this case.)

Finally, let's assume `buf` is `nil`.  (Or, if it's not nil, let's assume it has a capacity of 32768 bytes.  If it has a large capacity, we can just change the rest of the assumptions below, so that `src` has more bytes than there are in the buffer.)

So: we enter the loop with `size` holding the size of the temporary buffer `buf`, which is 32k.  Now suppose the source is a file that holds 64k.  It will take at least two `src.Read()` calls to read it!  Clearly we need an outer loop.  That's the overall `for` here.

Now suppose that `src.Read()` really does read the full 32k, so that `nr` is also `32 * 1024`.  The code will now call `dst.Write()`, passing the full 32k of data.  Unlike `src.Read()`—which is allowed to only read, say, 1k instead of the full 32k—the next chunk of code requires that `dst.Write()` write all 32k.  If it doesn't, the loop will `break` with `err` set to `ErrShortWrite`.

(An alternative would have been to keep calling `dst.Write()` with the remaining bytes, so that `dst.Write()` could write only 1k of the 32k, requiring 32 calls to get it all written.)

Note that `src.Read()` can choose to read only, say, 1k instead of 32k.  If the actual file is 64k, it will then take 64 trips, rather than 2, through the outer loop.  (An alternative choice would have been to force such a reader to implement the `LimitedReader`interface.  That's not as flexible, though, and is not what `LimitedReader` is intended for.)

Comment: ok, that makes sense now, I am just not clear about this part of your answer `Unlike src.Read()—which is allowed to only read, say, 1k instead of the full 32k—the next chunk of code requires that dst.Write() write all 32k`, I thought that write will get the same number of bytes read

Comment: The call to `dst.Write(buf[0:nr])` passes a slice whose length is `nr`. That function *can* return a short count, such as, say, 1024. What I'm getting at here is that if the call to `src.Read()` (which passes a 32k buffer in this example) returns 1024, the call to `dst.Write` passes just 1k to it and it should return 1k and all is fine. But if the call to `src.Read()` returns 32k and the call to `dst.Write()` passes 32k and `dst.Write()` returns 1k, the overall `copyBuffer` code will **return an error**. So it's not symmetric.

Comment: In fewer words: The reader can return a short read, and all is fine. (The shortened read becomes the full size of the read-and-then-write.) The writer **must not** return a shortened write; if he does so, `copyBuffer` **fails**.

Answer (score 1):

`func copyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error)`
when the total data size to copy if larger than `len(buf)`, `nr, er := src.Read(buf)` will try read at most `len(buf)` data every time.

that's how `copyBuffer` works:

```
for {
   copy `len(buf)` data from `src` to `dst`;
   if EOF {
       //done
       break;
   }
   if other Errors {
        return Error
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the normal case, you would just call [`Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) rather than [`CopyBuffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyBuffer).

```
func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error) {
    return copyBuffer(dst, src, nil)
}
```

The option to have a user-supplied buffer is, I think, just for extreme optimization scenarios.  The use of the word "`Buffer`" in the name is possibly a source of confusion since the function is *not* copying the buffer -- just using it internally.

There are two reasons for the looping...

1. The buffer might not be large enough to copy all of the data (the size of which is not necessarily known in advance) in one pass.
2. [`Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), though not ['Writer'](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), may return partial results when it makes sense to do so.

Regarding the second item, consider that the `Reader` does not necessarily represent a fixed file or data  buffer.  It could, instead, be a live stream from some other thread or process.  As such, there are many valid scenarios for stream data to be read and processed on an as-available basis.  *Although `CopyBuffer` doesn't do this, it still has to work with such behaviors from any `Reader`.*